# how to split column and show all the columns part of data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split the column name domain to domain_num, domain_alp

```
    domain count    year
1   [1, A]  0     1972.0
2   [1, B]  0     1972.0
3   [1, C]  0     1972.0
```

and show all the columns like this. here is the sample of my expected results.

```
 domain_num  domain_alp    count       year
1   1          A               0      1972.0
2   1          B               0      1972.0
3   1          C               0      1972.0
```

but when I tried this code to split the column.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['domain'].values.tolist(), columns=['domain_num','domain_alp'])
new_df
```

the result is being like this. it does not show all columns as I expected.

```
 domain_num  domain_alp    
        1          A            
        1          B             
        1          C
```

are any suggestions for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `concat` the result together

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['domain'].values.tolist(), columns=['domain_num','domain_alp'],index=df.index)

new_df=pd.concat([new_df ,df[['count','year']]],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to assign the columns to your original df:

```
df[['domain_num', 'domain_alp']] = pd.DataFrame(df.domain.tolist())
df.drop('domain', axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df
   count  year   domain_num domain_alp
0      0  1972.0          1          A
1      0  1972.0          1          B
2      0  1972.0          1          C
```